# Is earning money viewing advertisements online halal?

Tags: halal-haram, work, internet

I have recently heard that there are some internet websites which give small commission to the user who have made account on that site and view the advertisements published by that site.

Is such earning halal?

Comment: If the thing is bounded as you told, then it might be no problem, but there is a black business on it as far I know. In most of the country, at first they give some money to make people tempted and people become eager to invest in their other things and they made them trapped.

Comment: time is money, you are providing a service and getting paid. Can you elaborate on why you think it could be Haram? Is the content Haram?

Comment: +1 for not putting the actual sites

Comment: @AmericanMuslim A normal viewer who doesn't have accounts on these sites will not get paid and the site will not even ask them that if they wish to get paid for their service or not but those who have accounts are getting paid so it seems odd that a service is not being paid when in practical world it would get paid or at least the person is informed about the offer. Moreover no one knows whether the income a person is getting is from an interest source (Riba) which will make his income haram due to scholars 'Fatwa' on this subject. From the perspective of content it is surely haram.

Answer (score 3):

it is haram if it is lying/cheating/fraud/deception against advertisers who pay money to advertisement system for real advertisement views or clicks or certain actions on target site or by target phone number. and advertisement system is also cheated because it is waiting for true views and clicks from the sites which publish the ads. this site takes money from advertisement system but give false/artificial views, clicks etc to advertisement system.

but, if the site you are asking about is not using advertisement system and not cheating advertisers and the advertisers know how does it work, i.e. they intentionally pay just for any view by real human, it is probably allowed.

Comment: but there is a possibility that the money given to viewers is from an interest source which may be a great possibility so I am not fully convinced that whether that income is halal or not. But thanks for the input.

Comment: Good!..........